# A problem with insert data into cassandra

Tags: cassandra

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0jsh.png)this is the data structure of the table.

```
reviewer_id,reviewer_username,reviewer_personal_details,reviewer_preferences
```

```
1,RhMadsen,"{fname: 'Rhea', lanme: 'Madsen', age: 23}","{genre: {id: 14, name: 'Fantasy'}, production_company: {'name': 'Universal Pictures', 'id': 33}, production_country: {'iso_3166_1': 'US', 'name': 'United States of America'}}"
```

and my insert cmd is like this

```
INSERT INTO reviewers(
"reviewer_id",
"reviewer_username",
"reviewer_personal_details",
"reviewer_preferences"
) 
VALUES (
'30',
'Reilio',

{fname:'Jack',lname:'O'Reilly',age:'19'},
{"genres":{"id":'28',"name":'Action'},"production_company":{"id":'3333',"name":'Kangaroo Pictures'},"production_country":{"iso_3166_1":'AU',"name":'Australia'}}
);
```

and the shell always say its should end with a ;, but i have a ;. always stard a neew line. have no idea what happened.

Comment: show the table structure & UDT structure

Comment: ye the table and type is below:   ```CREATE TYPE personal_details (
   fname text,
   lname text,
   age int
   );
   
 CREATE TABLE reviewers (
   reviewer_id int,
   reviewer_username text,
   reviewer_personal_details personal_details,
   reviewer_preferences map<text, frozen<map<text, text>>>,
   PRIMARY KEY(reviewer_id),
   );```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a multiple problems in your statement:

1. you have single quote character inside this string: `lname:'O'Reilly'` - this lead that it's thinking that line is continuing. You need to escape it [correctly](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/escape_char_r.html) with either additional `'` character: `lname:'O''Reilly'`, or using `$$` for string boundaries.
2. you're using incorrect quotes for strings in the map - you're using double instead of single
3. you have incorrect data types for some fields, like, `reviewer_id`, etc.
4. you don't need to put column names into the double quotes - this is required only when you want to have case-sensitive names

The working query is following:

```
INSERT INTO reviewers(
reviewer_id,
reviewer_username,
reviewer_personal_details,
reviewer_preferences
)
VALUES (
30,
'Reilio',
{fname:'Jack',lname:$$O'Reilly$$, age:19},
{'genres':{'id':'28','name':'Action'},
'production_company':{'id':'3333','name':'Kangaroo Pictures'},
'production_country':{'iso_3166_1':'AU','name':'Australia'}
}
);
```

I recommend to read [Cassandra documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/) or grab the [free book about Cassandra](https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide) & read at least first part of it